# Rmarkdown - insert comment in-between brackets

Tags: r, r-markdown

This may seem like a basic question, but I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere.
Is there a way to enter a comment between the brackets of the chunk in `Rmarkdown`.
For example:

````
```{r some comments}
plot(cars)
```
````

I tries various types of charecters such as `##`, `>`,`<>` but they all still creted an error when I `Knit` the output to `html`.
The reason I want this is so that when I use `RStudio` I can collapse the chunks and have a comment there about what's in that chunk.

Thank you

Comment: If you want to comment inside some code chunk you have to put them outside the brackets using `#some_commente` or if you want to comment outside code chunk use `<!-- some comment --> `

Comment: using `{r #some_comment}` doesnt work. I realised that the comment shortcut also works for markdown comments, so that helps. Maybe it's not a good idea to have comments inside the brackets

Comment: Read my comment: outside the brackets and inside the code chunk. ` ```{r cars} #some_comment; summary(cars) ``` `

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer, but you can use `,` inside the brackets to separate parts and add a label (akin to a comment I would say):

````
``` {r, my-chunk, echo=FALSE, fig.height=4, dev='jpeg'}
```
````

Reference for more info: https://yihui.org/knitr/options/